# Getting a class from inside a package

Tags: python

I am trying to use the functions `__import__(...)` and `getattr(...)` to make an object of a class that is located inside a module. That module itself is included inside a package.

The class is named `TestScript`. It is located in a file named `TestScript.py`. The file is inside a folder named `TestScripts`. So from my understanding of python, the file `TestScript.py` is interpreted as module and the folder `TestScripts` is interpreted as package.

So, I tried it like this:

```
moduleName = 'TestScripts.TestScript'
className = 'TestScript'
module = __import__(moduleName)
targetClass = getattr(module, className)
instance = targetClass()
```

But an AttributeError occurs with the message "module 'TestScripts' has no attribute 'TestScript'".

I expected `instance` to be an object of the `TestScript` class after the execution of this code snippet. What do I miss?

Comment: You are trying to replicate `from TestScripts.Testscript import TestClass`?

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description.  You wrote that you have a module named `TestScript.py`, but in your example you try to import `'TestScripts.Script1`.  First of all, why use `__import__`?  It sounds like you might have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Second of all you're hitting a common confusion (which is very confusing) with how `__import__` treats sub-modules of a package.  In short, to do what you want, you must pass a non-empty `fromlist` argument.

Comment: I agree with Villius and Iguananaut, looks like you are missing the folder name: from package.filename(module) import Object. Then just use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the full explanation see [__import__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)

To make your code do what you want:

```
moduleName = 'Testscripts.TestScript'
className = 'TestClass'
module = __import__(moduleName) #could use fromlist here as @Iguananaut suggests
targetModule = getattr(module, "TestScript")
targetClass =  getattr(targetModule, className)
instance = targetClass()
```

*As a note - python docs strongly discourage direct use of* __import__